# Use Index Match Match To Find Multiple Values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have a spreadsheet that will have the text "Number Returned" multiple times in a header row (running from A1-Z1, but will expand and search area will be larger).  From A2:A55 I have names, I need a way to match the name to each instance of "Number Returned" and get a sum.  I see I can use `=Index(Match(Match))` to find one instance of "Number Returned" but could that formula be altered to add to a `SUM()` formula?

Here are a few snippets to show what I want (the total would need to be on a secondary worksheet not the same one if that matters)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use this `SUMIF` formula against your data:

```
=SUMIF($A$1:$M$1,"Number Returned",A2:M2)
```

by placing it in `N2` and copying down. *(you can adjust the end range and formula placement)*

To have the formula on a separate sheet, the formula provided by @ScottHoltzman in the comments may work better.

```
=SUMIF(Sheet2!$A$1:$M$1,"Number Returned",OFFSET(Sheet2!$A$1:$M$1,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$7,0)-1,0))
```

The range qualifications in the formula are based on your example data with the following notes:

- Sheet2 refers to where the actual data is
- assumes the reference list is columns A:B of with Header (Total Return) being row 1

As it was @ScottHoltzman who came up with a better answer, this has been made a community wiki.

If avoiding volatile formulas is a concern, the following replaces the [OFFSET function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592)'s role with the non-volatile [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a).<sub>jpd</sub>

```
=SUMIF(Sheet2!$A$1:$M$1, "Number Returned", INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$M, MATCH(A2, Sheet2!$A:$A, 0), 0))
```

Comment: Does this follow the same order of the names listed in A2:Z2?

Comment: since user wants formula on secondary sheet, this could be more dynamic by finding the exact row of the string and using offset to set the row to sum ... `=SUMIF(Sheet2!$A$1:$Z$1,"Number Returned",OFFSET(Sheet2!$A$1:$Z$1,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$7,0)-1,0))` ..  assumes data is on `Sheet2` and letter list starts in `A2`

Comment: @ScottHoltzman  and FartStopper I failed to read to the end of the post.  Scott's answer would be the best.  Scott throw yours into a new answer.

Comment: @ScottCraner - that's okay. You have a great answer.  I just added the comment as a way to take it a step further. Your answer works as well, if you qualify the sheets and ensure the string are in the exact same order, which is shown in the examples :)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, I added yours and made it a community wiki.  Feel free to edit.  I may not have explained it thorough enough.

Comment: @ScottCraner - It was very clear, I just made edits to condense the explanation and make it based on the original data provided in hopes that it's easier to understand. (Maybe, I went too far, but I tend to go for short, concise, communication in writing!)